# javascript TypeError: Cannot read property “0” from undefined loading JSON into Array

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am trying to learn how to use google maps I am loading a json object into a javascript array through AJAX, when I had the json data on the same webpage it loads in ok.  When I call the file I get

TypeError: Cannot read property “0” from undefined loading JSON into Array

This is how the JSON looks on the webpage if it's unremarked, it will process ok

Here is how I am perfoming my AJAX call I have added the JSON.parse to the response text.

I know get the error in the console

Unexpected token , in JSON at position 189

So my Json isn't correct but I copied and pasted it from the page into a text file??

```
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
markers =  JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText); 
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "Testdata.json", true);
http.send();

//Array of markers
/*
var markers = [
{
coords:{lat:53.745,lng:-0.338},
iconImage:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
content:'<h1>Lynn MA</h1>'
},
{
coords:{lat:53.747,lng:-0.340},
    iconImage:'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png',
content:'<h1>2 days before exceeds delivery date</h1>'
},
{
coords:{lat:53.750,lng:-0.220},
    iconImage:'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green.png'
}
];
*/

//loop through markers

for(var i = 0;i < 3;i++){
   addMarker(markers[i]);
}
```

in the chrome console it shows the JSON as after making a AJAX call.

```
"   {
"coords":{"lat":"53.745","lng":"-0.338"},
"iconImage":"https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
"content":"<h1>Lynn MA</h1>"
},
{
"coords":{"lat":"53.747","lng":"-0.340"},
    "iconImage":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png",
"content":"<h1>2 days before exceeds delivery date</h1>"
},
{
"coords":{"lat":"53.750","lng":"-0.220"},
    "iconImage":"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green.png"
}
"
```

The AJAX call must have worked as markers has data as the console shows, why does it process the JSON file ok when it's on the same page?  thanks for all help

Comment: Where is your `markers` array?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it's hard to say what the problem is.

Make sure when you return a value from PHP to JSON.encode it all.
After you get the return value from your call, make sure to do JSON.parse on the returned-result.

You can debug the return-value with an simple check:

`let returnValue = JSON.parse('returned-value from your ajax-call');
console.log(typeof returnValue); // this should be a array and/or object.`

If you do not JSON.parse the returned result. The typeof will return "string" as answer.
Good luck